# java ClassNotFoundException : com.buest.jcommander.ParameterException

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jcommander

I'm using intellij and came across this error while running testNg.

I verify 2 things:

- the class com.buest.jcommander.ParameterExeption exists under eternal libraries
- and jcommander path appears under project structure/modules.

note: when I run testNg via cmdline- the tests passed, but via intellij I get this error.

Comment: Is not a `c` missing in `Exception`?

Comment: BZW _eternal_ libraries is just what I am looping for.